# iPad crash: Unexpected view controller change in Supplementary column

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm receiving repetitive crash logs related to the UISplitController supplementary column.

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>
> Unexpected view controller change in Supplementary column for expanding <xxxx.CustomSplitViewController: 0x15bb0bf40>

I can't reproduce it and the logs have no reference at all to any of my code - I'm wondering if it can be somehow related to orientation changes.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Here is part of the crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x9904c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x15f54 objc_exception_throw
2  Foundation                     0x1306cc _userInfoForFileAndLine
3  UIKitCore                      0x991928 -[UISplitViewControllerPanelImpl panelController:separateSupplementaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x96699c __54-[UIPanelController _expandWithTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke_4
5  UIKitCore                      0xb0d78 +[UIPanelController _withDisabledAppearanceTransitions:forVisibleDescendantsOf:perform:]
6  UIKitCore                      0xb0940 -[UIPanelController _withDisabledAppearanceTransitionsPerform:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x9668c0 __54-[UIPanelController _expandWithTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke_3
8  UIKitCore                      0x1c6a08 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitionsAllowingAnimation:actions:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x966814 __54-[UIPanelController _expandWithTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke_2
10 UIKitCore                      0x174268 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
11 UIKitCore                      0x966760 __54-[UIPanelController _expandWithTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke
12 UIKitCore                      0x26fc28 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:]
13 UIKitCore                      0x529ae8 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations]
14 UIKitCore                      0x4f49ac -[_UIWindowAnimationController animateTransition:]
15 UIKitCore                      0xb70dc -[UIWindow _adjustSizeClassesAndResizeWindowToFrame:]
16 UIKitCore                      0x23e408 -[UIWindow _resizeWindowFrameToSceneBoundsIfNecessary]
17 UIKitCore                      0x461bd8 -[UIWindow _sceneBoundsDidChange]
18 UIKitCore                      0x5802e8 -[_UIScenefbsSceneBasedMetricsCalculator _updateMetricsOnWindows:animated:]
19 UIKitCore                      0x2b9fcc -[UIWindowScene _computeMetricsForWindows:animated:]
20 UIKitCore                      0x2e98a8 -[UIWindowScene _computeMetrics:]
21 UIKitCore                      0x270350 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:]
22 UIKitCore                      0x1b2340 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext
```

As for code, I set the controller on supplementary column once on viewDidLoad, and after that from user interaction (selecting a collection view cell on the primary column):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
    let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllerID.rawValue))
    splitViewController?.setViewController(vc, for: .supplementary)
    ...
}
```

And for rotation, on viewWillTransition I'm changing the display mode and split behaviour:

```
open override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    setDisplayMode()
}

func setDisplayMode() {
    let orientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
    if orientation?.isPortrait == true {
        splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary
        splitViewController?.preferredSplitBehavior = .overlay
    } else {
        splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .twoBesideSecondary
        splitViewController?.preferredSplitBehavior = .tile
    }
}
```

Update: The crash seems to be related to setting preferredDisplayMode and preferredSplitBehavior on rotation, but I still can't reproduce it. And I need the different settings depending on orientation.

Comment: But you do have a class called CustomSplitViewController right? So it _does_ relate to your code. Which you have not shown us.

Comment: @matt Fair enough, but that class does nothing except setting the status bar style. I've added the code I have for changing the supplementary controller, and for screen rotation. If there's anything else you'd want to see, I'll be happy to show it

Comment: "And for rotation, on viewWillTransition I'm changing the display mode and split behaviour" Yeah, I bet that's the issue. I can think of a number of potential flaws here. Note also that you get two of those in rapid succession whenever you go into the background.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't notice the double calls before, that may be it.